# How to replace the content of an element in a std::map with the content of another element

Tags: c++

I have a class "Token" and a class "ASTNode". ASTNode is a tree representation of a list of "Token"'s.

```
#define INTEGER "INTEGER"
#define ARRAY "ARRAY"

class Token {
    private:
        std::string type_t;
        std::string value_t;       
    public:
        Token() {
            type_t = "";
            value_t = "";
        }    
        Token(std::string type, std::string value) {
            type_t = type;
            value_t = value;
        }     
        ~Token(){}; 
        std::string value() { 
            return value_t; 
        }
        std::string type() { 
            return type_t; 
        }    
        std::string str() { 
            return ("Token(" + type_t + ", " + value_t + ")"); 
        }    
};
```

Class ASTNode

```
class ASTNode {
    public:        
        std::vector<ASTNode*> child;                    
        Token _token;                
        ASTNode() {};                        
        ASTNode(Token token) {
            _token = token;
        }        
        ~ASTNode() {}; 
        void make_child(ASTNode _node) {
            ASTNode *temp = new ASTNode(_node.token());
            temp->child = _node.child;
            child.push_back(temp);
        }            
        Token token() {
            return _token;
        }          
};
```

Now i have a `std::map<std::string, ASTNode>` where i want to store these "Array" nodes

```
std::map<std::string, ASTNode> ARRAYS;

    // create a node
ASTNode arr1(Token(ARRAY, "a"));        
arr1.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "1"));    
arr1.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "2"));
arr1.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "3"));
// store as ARRAYS["a"]
ARRAYS.insert(std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("a", arr1));
    
// create another node
ASTNode arr2(Token(ARRAY, "b"));
arr2.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "4"));    
arr2.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "5"));
arr2.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "6"));
// store as ARRAYS["b"]
ARRAYS.insert(std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("b", arr2));
```

My problem is when i want to create a new array to be a copy of an existing array. Lets say i want to create array `c` to be the same as array `a`

```
ARRAYS.insert( std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("c", arr1) );
```

Now i want to change the value of the 1st "array element" of the copy stored as `c`.

```
ASTNode tmp = ARRAYS["c"];
tmp.child[0]->_token = Token(INTEGER, "0");
//ARRAYS["c"] = tmp; 
ARRAYS.insert(std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("c", tmp));
```

but instead of only array `c` has been modified, array `a` also has been. How to change this so i can change only the copy of it?

Comment: You need to override the copy constructor of `ASTNode` so that the pointer data member is copied properly.

Comment: Do you mean like `ASTNode(const &ASTNode) { return *this; };`? I tried without success. But maybe i wrote it wrong?

Comment: Where are ARRAY and INTEGER defined?

Comment: They are just strings `#define INTEGER "INTEGER"` and `#define ARRAY "ARRAY"`. Sorry forgot and addet that.

Comment: your usage of the word "array" is a little confusing, because there is no array in your code

Comment: Of course its just a std::map but i think its reasonable what i mean by that. I guess an interpreter mostly does not store arrays like that but thats my implementation of it. I also called it `array nodes` btw :)

Comment: I guess it is because you are storing pointers in the child vector: you have a vector containing a pointer, when you copy the vector you also copy the same pointer in the other `ASTNode`. You should change the vector to contain the structure (and not the pointer - `std::vector<ASTNode> child`) or define a copy constructor which clone the objects referenced by the child vector elements

Comment: It would be easier to implement a copy constructor i guess. I tried so by adding `ASTNode(const &ASTNode) { return *this; };` to the ASTNode class but it didnt worked out. Could you tell me how to properly create such a constructor?

Comment: Why are you creating a copy of the array element, if the copy gets copied back into the map again(last code snippet)? Just modify the object stores inside the may directly: `ASTNode& value = ARRAYS["c"]; value.child[0]->_token = Token(INTEGER, "0");` that is if you really want to modify the map; `std::map::insert` won't update the value of an existing maping

Comment: @fabian i tried right now but there is no difference at all. Have you tried it out by yourself and it worked?

Comment: If you return `*this` you are actually copying the pointers inside the vector again... Something like `ASTNode(const &ASTNode other) { _token = other._token; for (ASTNode* node : other.child) { make_child(*node); } }` ? Anyway I don't see why you should not directly use a struct instead of pointers (`std::vector<ASTNode> child`), also because you will have memory leaks due to not freeing memory holden by the pointers.

Comment: @DDomen Wow it works without any changes in the code except adding this constructor to the class! Thank you so much! If you make it an answer i can accept it!

Comment: @DDomen If i add sometthing like `for(auto it = child.begin(); it != child.end(); it++) { free( *(it) ); }` to the destructor, would it avoid memory leaks?

Comment: Yes it can do, but usually `free` is used in strict memory management contexts, so you can use `delete` to call the destructor and free the memory more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a deep copy constructor of ASTNode and everything works well:

```cpp
ASTNode(ASTNode const & other) {
    _token = other._token;
    for (auto ochild: other.child)
        child.push_back(new ASTNode(*ochild));
}
```

You may also wish to add similar assignment `operator =` method implementation (but it is not needed to fix your current error, only above copy constructor is needed), assignment needs `Clear()` method for cleanup, which can be used in destructor also for freeing memory:

```cpp
ASTNode & operator = (ASTNode const & other) {
    Clear();
    _token = other._token;
    for (auto ochild: other.child)
        child.push_back(new ASTNode(*ochild));
    return *this;
}
void Clear() {
    for (auto c: child)
        delete c;
    child.clear();
    _token = Token();
}
~ASTNode() { Clear(); }
```

Full working code:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/z35dE9fGe)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

#define INTEGER "INTEGER"
#define ARRAY "ARRAY"

class Token {
    private:
        std::string type_t;
        std::string value_t;       
    public:
        Token() {
            type_t = "";
            value_t = "";
        }    
        Token(std::string type, std::string value) {
            type_t = type;
            value_t = value;
        }     
        ~Token(){}; 
        std::string value() { 
            return value_t; 
        }
        std::string type() { 
            return type_t; 
        }    
        std::string str() { 
            return ("Token(" + type_t + ", " + value_t + ")"); 
        }    
};

class ASTNode {
    public:        
        std::vector<ASTNode*> child;                    
        Token _token;                
        ASTNode() {};                        
        ASTNode(Token token) {
            _token = token;
        }        
        ASTNode(ASTNode const & other) {
            _token = other._token;
            for (auto ochild: other.child)
                child.push_back(new ASTNode(*ochild));
        }
        ASTNode & operator = (ASTNode const & other) {
            Clear();
            _token = other._token;
            for (auto ochild: other.child)
                child.push_back(new ASTNode(*ochild));
            return *this;
        }
        void Clear() {
            for (auto c: child)
                delete c;
            child.clear();
            _token = Token();
        }
        ~ASTNode() { Clear(); }
        void make_child(ASTNode _node) {
            ASTNode *temp = new ASTNode(_node.token());
            temp->child = _node.child;
            child.push_back(temp);
        }            
        Token token() {
            return _token;
        }          
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, ASTNode> ARRAYS;

    // create a node
    ASTNode arr1(Token(ARRAY, "a"));        
    arr1.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "1"));    
    arr1.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "2"));
    arr1.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "3"));
    // store as ARRAYS["a"]
    ARRAYS.insert(std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("a", arr1));
        
    // create another node
    ASTNode arr2(Token(ARRAY, "b"));
    arr2.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "4"));    
    arr2.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "5"));
    arr2.make_child(Token(INTEGER, "6"));
    // store as ARRAYS["b"]
    ARRAYS.insert(std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("b", arr2));

    std::cout << "a token " << arr1.child[0]->_token.value() << std::endl;

    ARRAYS.insert( std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("c", arr1) );

    ASTNode tmp = ARRAYS["c"];
    tmp.child[0]->_token = Token(INTEGER, "0");
    //ARRAYS["c"] = tmp; 
    ARRAYS.insert(std::pair<std::string, ASTNode>("c", tmp));

    std::cout << "a token " << arr1.child[0]->_token.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Output before change:

```
a token 1
a token 0
```

Output after change:

```
a token 1
a token 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
class ASTNode {
    public:        
        std::vector<ASTNode*> child;                    
        Token _token;                
        ASTNode() {};                        
        ASTNode(Token token) {
            _token = token;
        }
        ASTNode(const &ASTNode other) {
            _token = other._token;
            for (ASTNode* node : other.child) { make_child(*node); }
        }
        ~ASTNode() {
           // YOU REALLY SHOULD FREE YOUR VECTOR HERE!
           // for example:
           for (ASTNode* node : child) { delete node; }
        }; 
        void make_child(ASTNode _node) {
            ASTNode *temp = new ASTNode(_node.token());
            temp->child = _node.child;
            child.push_back(temp);
        }            
        Token token() {
            return _token;
        }          
};
```

## Explanation

When you copy an `ASTNode` (i.e. with `ASTNode tmp = ARRAYS["c"];`) you are actually copying the memory hole by the elements of the struct.

`Token` is simply a couple of strings, the `std::string` copy constructor ensure you will have two different instances of the same string.

`std::vector<ASTNode*>` is in the underlying an array, but the elements are copyied in the new memory when the copy constructor is called. When you copy the elements of this array, you are copying a number which stores the address of the memory of an object, but not the object itself. That address is called pointer.

We can explain this by assuming a real case: imagine there are three houses in `Time Square, Manhattan`, one red at number 0, one green at 1 and one blue at 2. When you hold a vector of pointers you are storing just the addresses: `[ "Time Square, Manhattan, 0", "Time Square, Manhattan, 1", "Time Square, Manhattan, 2" ]`. Copying this vector will copy just the address, but the houses does not change. `tmp.child[0]` and `arr1.child[0]` are both the address `"Time Square, Manhattan, 0"` which refer to the same red house.

When you instead hold a vector of instances (`std::vector<ASTNode>`) you are not interested in the address but in the shape, color and physical aspect of the house. So you will copy the aspect of the red house but it can be placed for example at `"Cooper Square, Manhattan, 0"`. In the aspects are the same houses, but they are two different buildings in two different places of Manhattan.

So by doing `tmp.child[0]->_token = Token(INTEGER, "0");` you are actually saying: "The token of the house at `Time Square, Manhattan, 0` is now `Token(INTEGER, "0")`". Every other vector that has saved that address will "see" the same changes, because the building is changed in someway.

Now you have two options:

1. Use `std::vector<ASTNode>` so the default copy constructor will copy the aspect of the house, but keeping two different buildings.
2. Make sure to create a copy of the building in a different place (memory location) so you can modify the new building without touching the old one (see solution).

**NOTE:** Always ensure you destroy the buildings you do not need anymore! (see solution destructor)